# How can I get log value of a negative value?

Tags: java, logarithm, natural-logarithm

I have a function of the following table.

| input: e | output: 1 << e |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `1` |
| `1` | `2` |
| ... | ... |
| `31` | `-2147483648` |

```java
static int value(int exponent) {
    return 1 << exponent;
}
```

Now, how can I get the `exponent` from a `value`?

I tried the following code and it fails for the last entry of `-2147483648`.

```java
int exponent(int value) {
    return (int) (Math.log(value) / Math.log(2)); // -> NaN / Math.log(2)
}
```

And I managed to fix it like this.

```java
int exponent(int value) {
    if (value == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
       return (int) (Math.log(value - 1) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
    }
    return (int) (Math.log(value) / Math.log(2));
}
```

Is there any better/proper way to do this?

Comment: Use `31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value)`.

Comment: @AlexR Thank you for your comment. Would you like add an answer for that? Don't be shy. It'll help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros(int)) for that. According to its JavaDoc:

> Note that this method is closely related to the logarithm base 2. For all positive int values x:
>
> ```
> floor(log2(x)) = 31 - numberOfLeadingZeros(x)
> ceil(log2(x)) = 32 - numberOfLeadingZeros(x - 1)
> ```

To implement your `exponent` method, simply copy what the JavaDoc suggests:

```java
int exponent(int value) {
    return 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value);
}
```

Note that this also works for negative numbers in your case, even though the logarithm is not defined for non-positive numbers: For all negative numbers, the left-most bit will be 1 due to their representation in the two's complement. Therefore, for any negative value, `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros` returns 0, and hence your `exponent` method calculates `31`.

Also note, that if `value == 0`, then `exponent` returns `-1` which is a case you might want to take care of. For example, you could throw an `IllegalArgumentException` since the logarithm is undefined for `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros()` as *Alex R* has suggested in their answer would perfectly fine for positive input, but for any negative number

```
31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value)
```

would be evaluated as `31` because the very first bit of every negative number is `1`.

This result (exponent of `31`) makes sense for `-2147483648` since 2^31 = 2147483648 (as *Alex R* stated in their answer), but not for `-1`, `-16`, `-256`, etc.

To get the correct result for a negative input, you need to work with the absolute value of the given input.

In order to treat the case when the given is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (which has no positive equivalent in `int` type because `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is less by one) without additional checks, you can use `long`.

Here's one of the way to implement it using bitwise logic:

```
public static int exponent(int value) {
    if (value == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    
    long mod = Math.abs((long) value);
    
    long mask = 1;
    int exp = 31;
    
    while ((mask << exp & mod) == 0) { // until left bit is not 1, decrement the exponent
        exp--;
    }
    
    return exp;
}
```

Simple demonstration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("value: 1" + "\texponent: " + exponent(1));
    System.out.println("value: 2" + "\texponent: " + exponent(2));
    System.out.println("value: 8" + "\texponent: " + exponent(8));
    System.out.println("value: 32" + "\texponent: " + exponent(32));
    System.out.println("value: 64" + "\texponent: " + exponent(64));
    System.out.println("value: 256" + "\texponent: " + exponent(256));
    System.out.println("value: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE + "\texponent: " + exponent(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    
    System.out.println("value: -1" + "\texponent: " + exponent(-1));
    System.out.println("value: -2" + "\texponent: " + exponent(-2));
    System.out.println("value: -8" + "\texponent: " + exponent(-8));
    System.out.println("value: -32" + "\texponent: " + exponent(-32));
    System.out.println("value: -64" + "\texponent: " + exponent(-64));
    System.out.println("value: -256" + "\texponent: " + exponent(-256));
    System.out.println("value: " + Integer.MIN_VALUE + "\texponent: " + exponent(Integer.MIN_VALUE));
}
```

Output:

```
value: 1    exponent: 0
value: 2    exponent: 1
value: 8    exponent: 3
value: 32   exponent: 5
value: 64   exponent: 6
value: 256  exponent: 8
value: 2147483647   exponent: 30

value: -1   exponent: 0
value: -2   exponent: 1
value: -8   exponent: 3
value: -32  exponent: 5
value: -64  exponent: 6
value: -256 exponent: 8
value: -2147483648  exponent: 31
```

Comment: That's a nice addition! I interpreted OP's question more like "treat ints as unsigned". Btw. there is also an equivalent of the method I suggested using for longs, so you could simplify your implementation to: `63 - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(Math.abs((long) value))`